# long long equation alignment

Tags: equations

How can I write these equations aligned from left??

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
y_{1}^{h}(t)= 10.594e^{0.9374t}-(0.29721 + 1.4316i)e^{- 0.9188 + 7.27it}\\ - (0.29721 - 1.4316i)e^{- 7.27it - 0.9188} - (1.2754 - 18.405i)e^{- 0.0546 + 2.6708it} \\- 11.28e^{-0.9907t} - (1.2754 + 18.405i)e^{- 2.6708it - 0.0546}
\\
y_{2}^{h}(t)=29.984e^{0.9374t} - (0.075124 + 0.53372i)e^{- 0.9188 + 7.27it}\\ - (0.075124 - 0.53372i)e^{-7.27it - 0.918} -(0.27737 + 6.8994i)e^{- 0.0546 + 2.6708it}\\ - 30.668e^{-0.9907t} - (0.27737 - 6.8994i)e^{- 2.6708it - 0.0546}
   \\
y_{3}^{h}(t)=(0.38453 + 10.357i) e^{- 0.0546 + 2.6708it}- (1.042 - 10.531i)e^{- 0.9188 + 7.27it}\\ - (1.042 + 10.531i)e^{- 7.27it - 0.9188} + 9.1448e^{0.9374t} - 10.312e^{-0.9907t} \\+ (0.38453 - 10.357i)e^{- 2.6708it - 0.0546}

\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indicate the alignment point with an `&`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
y_{1}^{h}(t) &= 10.594e^{0.9374t}-(0.29721 + 1.4316i)e^{- 0.9188 + 7.27it}\\ 
&- (0.29721 - 1.4316i)e^{- 7.27it - 0.9188} - (1.2754 - 18.405i)e^{- 0.0546 + 2.6708it} \\
&- 11.28e^{-0.9907t} - (1.2754 + 18.405i)e^{- 2.6708it - 0.0546}
\\
y_{2}^{h}(t) &=29.984e^{0.9374t} - (0.075124 + 0.53372i)e^{- 0.9188 + 7.27it}\\ 
&- (0.075124 - 0.53372i)e^{-7.27it - 0.918} -(0.27737 + 6.8994i)e^{- 0.0546 + 2.6708it}\\ 
&- 30.668e^{-0.9907t} - (0.27737 - 6.8994i)e^{- 2.6708it - 0.0546}
   \\
y_{3}^{h}(t)&=(0.38453 + 10.357i) e^{- 0.0546 + 2.6708it}- (1.042 - 10.531i)e^{- 0.9188 + 7.27it}\\ 
&- (1.042 + 10.531i)e^{- 7.27it - 0.9188} + 9.1448e^{0.9374t} - 10.312e^{-0.9907t} \\
&+ (0.38453 - 10.357i)e^{- 2.6708it - 0.0546}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might also try placing two summands in the same line, but it would be even harder to read than it is with just one per line.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
y_{1}^{h}(t)&= 10.594e^{0.9374t}
  \\
  &\qquad - (0.29721 + 1.4316i)e^{- 0.9188 + 7.27it}
  \\
  &\qquad - (0.29721 - 1.4316i)e^{- 7.27it - 0.9188}
  \\
  &\qquad - (1.2754 - 18.405i)e^{- 0.0546 + 2.6708it}
  \\
  &\qquad - 11.28e^{-0.9907t}
  \\
  &\qquad - (1.2754 + 18.405i)e^{- 2.6708it - 0.0546}
\\[2ex]
y_{2}^{h}(t)&= 29.984e^{0.9374t}
  \\
  &\qquad - (0.075124 + 0.53372i)e^{- 0.9188 + 7.27it}
  \\
  &\qquad - (0.075124 - 0.53372i)e^{-7.27it - 0.918}
  \\
  &\qquad -(0.27737 + 6.8994i)e^{- 0.0546 + 2.6708it}
  \\
  &\qquad - 30.668e^{-0.9907t}
  \\
  &\qquad - (0.27737 - 6.8994i)e^{- 2.6708it - 0.0546}
\\[2ex]
y_{3}^{h}(t)&= (0.38453 + 10.357i)e^{- 0.0546 + 2.6708it}
  \\
  &\qquad - (1.042 - 10.531i)e^{- 0.9188 + 7.27it}
  \\
  &\qquad - (1.042 + 10.531i)e^{- 7.27it - 0.9188}
  \\
  &\qquad + 9.1448e^{0.9374t}
  \\
  &\qquad - 10.312e^{-0.9907t}
  \\
  &\qquad+ (0.38453 - 10.357i)e^{- 2.6708it - 0.0546}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]